# Google Cloud + Google Domains DNS HTTP not working but HTTPS is

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, https, http, google-domains

I have a website hosted on Google Cloud with a paid domain name registered at Google Domains. I opted in for the SSL option so the website can be served with HTTPS.

In the domain forwarding setting for DNS, I have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) redirecting to https://example.com

The following URLs work for navigating to the site:

- https://www.example.com
- https://example.com
- http://www.example.com

However the following DOESN'T work:

- http://example.com

When I go to http://example.com, I instantly get the "**This page isn't working**" error... ...."**example.com** didn't send any data."...
..."ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

There is probably a lot of additional information needed for a general person to answer this; but, I'm hoping someone with experience with Google Cloud and Google Domains can fill in the blanks and answer this for me. I'm afraid to tinker much because 3 of 4 scenarios above are working so that's better than 0 of 4. And TTL makes it hard to test changes to the current configuration. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is a screenshot of my Google Domains DNS settings page (redacted): [image]

Also, here is a screenshot of my Google Cloud VPC Network IP Addresses settings page (redacted):
[image]

Edit, I'll be happy to provide any additional information per request.

Comment: `in MS Edge` - is this a problem specifically in MS Edge? or do all browsers behave the same

Comment: `for DNS, I have www.example.com redirecting to https://example.com` I've not seen a DNS setting for redirecting web traffic. What type of record is that?.

Comment: @JaromandaX this happens in all browsers. Also, the forwarding is a feature in Google Domains DNS tab.

Comment: Can you give few details like what is the web server you are using, it's configuration and DNS records

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni I added screenshots of the configuration, please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: Hi `Jim22510` can you try adding a rule for [http://example.com](http://example.com) in your domain forwarding